# I am trying to get some data from user input into a JSON file.I get this message

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I get this JSON error that tells me that I have a syntax error an I can't figure out where I made the mistake. I have provided the code in case if helps.

```
 var isNode= typeof module !=="undefined"
var clientData;
var auxClientData;
var aux=[];
var k=0;
if (!isNode)
{
var storedObjects=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects"));
console.log(storedObjects);




var ok=false;
buttonConfirm.addEventListener("click",function(){
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
    {
        var inputShow=inputs[i].value;
        if (inputShow!=null && inputShow!="")
                {
                    aux[k++]=inputShow; 
               }
               else
               {
                   alert("ALL THE FIELDS MUST BE COMPLETED! ");
                   ok=true;
                   break;
               }
    }
     clientData={fullName:aux[0],emailAddress:aux[1],phoneNumber:aux[2]};
    //localStorage.setItem("clientData",JSON.stringify(clientData));
   // console.log(clientData);
    if (ok==true){
        alert("THANK YOU FOR YOUR PURCHASE! CHECK YOUR E-MAIL")
    }
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clientData)));
})

}
else
{
    var clientData={"fullName":aux[0],"emailAddress":aux[1],"phoneNumber":aux[2]};
    var fs=require("fs");
     auxClientData=JSON.stringify(clientData);

    fs.writeFile("clients.json",auxClientData,finished)
    function finished()
    {
        console.log("ok");
        var ok=fs.readFileSync("clients.json");
        var test=JSON.parse(ok);
        console.log(test);

    }

}
```

Here is the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()

Comment: Your error says that it can't parse the JSON. What "JSON" are you trying to parse?
`localStorage.getItem("objects")`, and `ok` (`fs.readFileSync("clients.json")`), what are these values?

Comment: You're trying to parse the 'objects' item from local storage to JSON. The value for this item probably isn't formatted as proper JSON.

Comment: Sounds like you do not have JSON. Look at what you are parsing. console.log() is your friend.

Comment: what does the console log of  clientData from clientData={"fullName":aux[0],"emailAddress":aux[1],"phoneNumber":aux[2]}; look like?

Comment: @NeilLocketz the objects one is something that I used to get data from a previous page and ok is just a varaible

Comment: the 'objects' sounds like it is not a string containing valid JSON. Perhaps you don't need to parse it?

Comment: @Squiggs so the console log looks like this: {fullName: "abc", emailAddress: "abcd", phoneNumber: "abcde"}
__proto__: Object

Comment: @Squiggs and the stringified 'clientData' looks like this and I checked wheter it is a valid JSON string or not : {"fullName":"abc","emailAddress":"abcd","phoneNumber":"abcde"}

Comment: The problem is with clientData, not with the first JSON.parse("objects")

Comment: Are you reading it before the file has a chance to be written? i.e. move the last bits inside the finished function.

Comment: @Squiggs it kind of works now, but i get the 'undefined' in my clients.json and this error in the command prompt: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Comment: ok, if the code was never successfully writing to the file, I'd start exploring this line fs.writeFile("clients.json",auxClientData,finished) - is it possible your file permissions are incorrect or anything? Can you write a simple text string to a file as it stands?

Comment: @Squiggs I get the [object Object] one now, if I test something simple like this:  var json={nume:"tudors",year:2020};
    fs.writeFile("clients.json",json,finished)
    function finished()
    {
        console.log("ok");
        var ok=fs.readFileSync("clients.json");
        var test=JSON.parse(ok);
        console.log(test);
        
    }
 
}

Comment: @Squiggs I figured out the problem, it was this line :  clientData={fullName:aux[0],emailAddress:aux[1],phoneNumber:aux[2]}; how do I transform this into a JSON format? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realised what the problem is :

```
 var clientData;
 auxClientData=JSON.stringify(clientData);
```

clientData inside your else statement is never set and it will be undefined. so you will need to redefine it inside the else. aux will need to be available and in scope further up your program for this to work. You can confirm my assumption by manually setting clientData to something else inside the else statement.

```
else
{
    var fs=require("fs");
    clientData={"fullName":aux[0],"emailAddress":aux[1],"phoneNumber":aux[2]};
     auxClientData=JSON.stringify(clientData);
    fs.writeFile("clients.json",auxClientData,finished)
    function finished()
    {
        console.log("ok");
    }
    var ok=fs.readFileSync("clients.json");
    var test=JSON.parse(ok);
    console.log(test);

}
```

------------------------------YOUR CODE.

```
var isNode = typeof module !== "undefined"
var clientData;
var auxClientData;
var aux = [];
var k = 0;

if (!isNode) {

    // INSIDE THE IF 
    var storedObjects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects"));
    console.log(storedObjects);
    var ok = false;
    //add a listener inside the if statement for the click. 
    buttonConfirm.addEventListener("click", function () {
         // when it is clicked.
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

            var inputShow = inputs[i].value;
            if (inputShow != null && inputShow != "") {
                //POPULATE THE AUX ARRAY adding one to k each time?
                // seems weird, why is this not aux[i] = inputShow;
                aux[k++] = inputShow;
            }
            else {
                alert("ALL THE FIELDS MUST BE COMPLETED! ");
                ok = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        clientData = { fullName: aux[0], emailAddress: aux[1], phoneNumber: aux[2] };
        //localStorage.setItem("clientData",JSON.stringify(clientData));
        // console.log(clientData);
        if (ok == true) {
            alert("THANK YOU FOR YOUR PURCHASE! CHECK YOUR E-MAIL")
        }
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clientData)));
    })

}
else {

    //inside the else. 
    //aux is an empty array here. so aux[0] = undefined, aux[1] = undefined etc.
    //i.e. the button hasn't been pressed to populate it at this point.
    var clientData = { "fullName": aux[0], "emailAddress": aux[1], "phoneNumber": aux[2] };
    var fs = require("fs");
    auxClientData = JSON.stringify(clientData);

    fs.writeFile("clients.json", auxClientData, finished)
    function finished() {
        console.log("ok");
        var ok = fs.readFileSync("clients.json");
        var test = JSON.parse(ok);
        console.log(test);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is now with the aux[0],aux[1] and aux[2]. I get Cannot read property '0' of undefined. I have something like this when I set the value for each "aux": for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
    {
        var inputShow=inputs[i].value;
        if (inputShow!=null && inputShow!="")
                {
                    aux[k++]=inputShow; 
               }
               else
               {
                   alert("ALL THE FIELDS MUST BE COMPLETED! ");
                   ok=true;
                   break;
               }
    }

Comment: as I say, you need to check that variable (wherever it comes from) is in scope in order for it to be used at that point of the program.  You don't illustrate in your question where or how aux is defined. I would suggest you update your question with more complete detail of your code.

Comment: Your aux variable is only populated inside the first if statement inside the button handler, therefore it is empty when you try and access it inside the else statement. see above.

Comment: after I made aux and k global variables, in the JSON file I get an empty {}

Comment: In order to populate it do I have to get the same code inside the else statement?And does that work when using nodeJS?